fluentd | How to handle "%s" placeholders dynamically in Fluentd with "massage" and "args" fields?
I'm trying to create a full_message field in Fluentd based on two fields:

msg, which contains a string with placeholders like %s (can be more than one)

args, which contains the values to substitute into the placeholders (either as a string or an array).


It seems that Fluentd's ${...} syntax doesn't support complex Ruby expressions.
How can I achieve this functionality in Fluentd, especially for cases where msg has multiple placeholders (e.g., %s %s) and args provides the corresponding values?
Thanks!

do you know if %s occurrences are fixed ones in msg field?

@Imran No, each msg can have a different amount of occurrences :\

I don't see some examples from you but something like this might help you get started. With record_transformer filter plugin and enable_ruby, you can write some ruby code to generate the full_message.
<source>
  @type dummy
  dummy [
    {"msg":"Hello, %s. You did %s","args":["Tony", "something awesome"]},
    {"msg":"Hello, %s. You did %s again, here is the %s","args":["Tony", "something awesome", "trophy"]}
    ]
  tag main_tag
</source>

<filter main_tag>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"
    tag ${tag}
    full_message ${record["msg"] % record["args"]}
  </record>
</filter>

<match main_tag>
  @type stdout
</match>

This should generate, following output.
2024-12-25 16:50:52 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
2024-12-25 16:50:53.057334958 +0000 main_tag: {"msg":"Hello, %s. You did %s","args":["Tony","something awesome"],"hostname":"552a9dbcdc76","tag":"main_tag","full_message":"Hello, Tony. You did something awesome"}
2024-12-25 16:50:54.061259383 +0000 main_tag: {"msg":"Hello, %s. You did %s again, here is the %s","args":["Tony","something awesome","trophy"],"hostname":"552a9dbcdc76","tag":"main_tag","full_message":"Hello, Tony. You did something awesome again, here is the trophy"}

